# Best way to use Canvas with many paths as children

Tags: xaml, canvas, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

We are currently using Canvas to render Barcode in UI for WinRT, UWP. We achieve this by adding each points(black dots in the QR Barcode) as paths in the canvas, which on rendering uses more time to display the Barcode. What is the efficient way to achieve this with high performance.

QR Barcode Image:

[image]

Comment: Render once to an off screen canvas then render that canvas when needed. Or maybe use the Path2D interface https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D

Comment: Use a [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243259)?

Comment: the zxing library gives you the image. you aware of that?

Comment: I have achieved this by using WriteableBitmap, off screen canvas doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this, by drawing the Barcode as image instead of canvas.

```
    public WriteableBitmap Render()
    {

        byte[] foreground = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 255 };
        byte[] background = new byte[] { 0, 100, 0, 255 };
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(2, 2);

        bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write(foreground, 0, 4);
        bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write(background, 0, 4);
        bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write(foreground, 0, 4);
        bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write(background, 0, 4);


        bmp.Invalidate();
        return bmp;
    }
```